# LibGdx -simple game with different type of drops

Tags: libgdx

Hope everyone knows the basic Libgdx game in this link:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/A-simple-game

In the simple game,rain drops are falling randomly from the top,that is of one type.
In my case,I want to implement the same thing,as drops.The difference is that,there are four type of drops.When it collides with another object,four should show four different characteristics.

In short,I created a Drop class with its object and array and can spawn drop objects too.

```
   Drop drop=new Drop();
   private Array<Drop> drops=new Array<Drop>();
```

But what if I want to define individual attributes for drops in this case?
I want the drop object to be categorized of four types. For example have different colors yellow,red,green and blue.Also four kind of drops should fall randomly from top.

In which way,and how I should implement such a concept?

It would be very helpful if I get some idea on this.

**Edit:**

I have an abstract class Drop and .I am not passing texture and rectangle in the constructor.Because graphics are not available for the project right now.I am planning to assign it in a later stage.As of now,everything I am doing it with shaperenderer.

I have create() method for three distinct colored drops in my objectFactory class where I used to create all objects:

```
 public YellowDrop createYellow(){
    YellowDrop yellow = new YellowDrop();
    yellow.setSize(100f,100f);
    yellow.setPosition(MathUtils.random(0, 800),1280);
    return yellow;
}
public RedDrop createRed(){
    RedDrop red = new RedDrop();
    red.setSize(100f,100f);
    red.setPosition(MathUtils.random(0, 800),1280);
    return red;
}
public GreenDrop createGreen(){
    GreenDrop green = new GreenDrop();
    green.setSize(100f,100f);
    green.setPosition(MathUtils.random(0, 800),1280);
    return green;
}
```

And I written createRandomDrop() code like this(For me,your code is confusing though.How can I use that colon symbol there in a method?I never used it.)

private Block createRandomDrop() {
     switch (MathUtils.random(0, 3)) {
     case 0 : 
         System.out.println("000000");
         return objectFactory.createYellow();
     case 1 : 
         return objectFactory.createGreen();

```
 case 2 : return objectFactory.createRed(); 
 default:
     return objectFactory.createGreen();
```

}
}
  Here I am confused about how to return the individual drop object.
  Even though I have written the call like this:

```
if(TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastDropTime > 1000000000) {
  drops.add(createRandomDrop());  
  } 

private void updateBlocks(float delta) {

   Iterator<Drop> iter = drops.iterator();
      while(iter.hasNext()) {
         Drop b = iter.next();
        b.update(delta);//moving drop from top to bottom in update()
         if(b.getY()<0) iter.remove();
      }
    //  System.out.println(drops.size);
```

}

At last I am drawing the shaperenderer for all array elements:

```
  for (Drop b : drops) {
    b.drawDebug(shapeRenderer);}
```

This drawdebug() is in Drop class and I am overriding it

```
  public void drawDebug(ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer) {
    shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    shapeRenderer.rect(collisionRectangle.x, collisionRectangle.y, 
   collisionRectangle.width,
            collisionRectangle.height);
 }
```

problem is that,too many drops are getting created and overlapping.May be the switch case creates the problem.

Comment: The person who down voted can at least leave a comment .So that I can understand what I did wrong and improve my question.I am sincerely trying to get an answer and how it feels if someone down vote simply and go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your problem? This is simple.

Create 4 children of Drop class. yellowDrop, greenDrop, etc... And create collide() method in Drop class which will implement same functionality for all children.

Something like this:

```
abstract class Drop {

     abstract Texture tex;
     abstract Rectangle rect;

     Drop(Texture tex, Rectangle rect){ 
         // initialize values here
     }

     void showCollideAnimation(){  // example. here you can create your own void to show different characteristics.
           tex.blabla()     
     }

     void collide(){
           showCollideAnimation();
     }

     // also draw, update methods etc... Hope you got that they should do functionality same for all children
}
```

And then create child that will override showCollideAnimation method.

```
class GreenDrop extends Drop {

        @override
        void showCollideAnimation(){  
             ....     // here you pass effect for Green child
        }
}
```

To chose random child you can just create function that returns Drop

```
Drop createRandomDrop(Rectangle rect): Drop {

            switch (MathUtils.random(0, 3)) {
                case 0 : return new YellowDrop(Texture("pathToYellowTexture"), rect) break;
                case 1 : return new GreenDrop(Texture("pathToGreenTexture"), rect) break;
                // etc.
            }

}
```

Now you can fill ArrayList of Drops.

```
private ArrayList<Drop> drops = new ArrayList<Drop>();

in render method:

if(TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastDropTime > 1000000000) {
      drops.add(createRandomDrop(Texture(""), Rectangle()));  // specify texture and rectangle yourself
}
```

Comment: But how I will create dynamic array of type Drop that contain all these inherited child class objects?

Comment: Please specify how to add child class object to the array.I never used it and don't have much idea.It would be very helpful.

Comment: I tried this but stuck again.After creating the child objects,how to iterate the drops array?For that object should be created it seems.But how I will create a common object?Drop class is abstract.

Comment: I tried without using abstract also.But when I create object for iteration,it is throwing nullpointerexception on the object created.Also return statement after switch case in createRandomDrop() is confusing.

Comment: It is almost working now!.Thanks for your help!Only thing is that I have to control the number of drops getting created from switch.I hope then everything will b fine.Thanks a lot!@ icarumbas